# What is miner Mining?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ether

I am new to blockchain and ethereum. I created a private network with two nodes, I have couple of questions:

1. After starting the miner it starts mining even if there is no transaction performed. So what is the miner mining and what is the significance of it?
2. When I transfer some ether to another using the mist wallet it says it is pending 12 approvals, how we reach to this figure of 12 approvals, is it configurable.?

TIA

Comment: For answer to first part of your question please see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6648/in-a-private-blockchain-why-do-miners-keep-adding-empty-blocks-to-the-blockchai

Comment: And part two is answered [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3488/what-does-the-12-confirmations-mean-in-the-mist-when-sending-transactions)

Comment: Hi there. To avoid duplication in other people posting answers, and to prevent this question going stale (because it's been answered in the comments), I'm going to flag it as a duplicate (to the first answer pointed to in the comments).

Answer (score 2):

For the  answer of your first question :-
 **Miners produce blocks which are checked for validity by other participating nodes.** **The process of finalizing a block during mining involves following steps:-**
 **1. Determine Uncles

 2. Determine and process Transactions

 3. Apply mining Rewards

 4. Compute mining proof of work(POW)**